# Changing gamerule from server console has no effect

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-spigot

I implemented a datapack, that changes certain gamerules like mobGriefing or doInsomnia based on the preferences of the players that are currently playing on the server. The datapack works in a test world realiable, but when I put it on the server the gamerule changes have no effect.

If I check the current state of the gamerule with the server console, the gamerules change if I change my preferences ingame. But if check the same thing with the server chat and an OP-Account, nothing changes. And the output from the chat seems to be the correct one.

#### Tests

I tested this with mobGriefing. I am the only player online, so if I change my preferences with the datapack they instantly take effect.

- I started with no preference set. So mobGriefing was set to the default, which is `true`, both in console and in the chat.
- If I now set my preference to `false`, the gamerule should switch to false.
- But it did that only on the console. (Ignore the server restart, it didn't change anything)

[image: Server console on the left, Game on the right]

- And it had no effect ingame. I tested it with a creeper.

The server runs on spigot in Java 1.16.4. I have not much experience with spigot, but I know commands and functions pretty well.

Do you have any idea, what causes this or how it could be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spigot gamerules are world specific. Download the [Multiverse](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/bukkit-plugins/multiverse-core) plugin and `/mv gamerule mobGriefing false world_the_nether`.

Answer (score 0):

*You said you changed the value to "False"*

*The value must be lowercase, as in "false" same with "true".*

Was just a typo, not actually the problem

Comment: no, thats nothing, you can see in the game window that it notices the function.

Comment: Edited my post. I just wrote that wrong in the post here. The commands were working and I got correct command feedback on them.